# 'string' does not contain a definition for 'IsInt' and no extension method 'IsInt' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found

Tags: asp.net, web

The isInt doesn't seem to work when put into a class file and i don't understand why. When used within my code it works fine it's just it doesn't like x.IsInt when i moved it into a class file?

```
public static Boolean Integervalid(string x)
{

    bool i = false;

    if (x.IsInt())
    {
        i = true;
    }

    return i;
}
```

Comment: There must be an extension method `IsInt()`

Comment: Is it `isInt` or  `IsInt`? C# is case sensitive.

Comment: Probably IsInt is defined in  a different namespace than the class that contains Integervalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because `IsInt()` is an extension method that's in `System.Web.WebPages.dll`, and you don't have a reference to it.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.webpages.stringextensions.isint.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need add the following assembly:
System.Web.WebPages (in System.Web.WebPages.dll)

see: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.webpages.stringextensions.isint(v=vs.111).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.webpages.stringextensions.isint%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

I suggest to use TryParse to be more independent from the WebPages.dll.
TryParse is included in mscorlib

```
int number;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
```

see: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)